# Handling selenium exceptions and alertbox in python

Tags: python, selenium, exception, automation

I am using selenium for some automation work. Sorry for long discription. I am new with Python.
Basically there is the students result portal. where we need to enter a seat number and click on OK button to see the result. On click of the submit new window is opened where the result is displayed using table in html.

1. If seat number is invalid alertbox is opened indicating invalid seat no and ok option to close.

Problem:

1. I want to loop through the roll numbers from lets say 1500 to 1600. if 1501 roll number is invalid alertbox is shown. I want to close the alertbox and continue with roll no 1502.

if the value of the result is more than 96% i want to increase the count by 1.
2. Once the result is opened after doing calculation I want to  close the newly opened window and enter the next seat number again. and continue with calculation

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
web = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='J:\stuff\soft\chromedriver.exe')
web.get('https://msbte.org.in/DISRESLIVE2021CRSLDSEP/frmALYSUM21PBDisplay.aspx')

# variable to store the result
resultCount = 0

rlstart = 156857
rlend = 157299

try:
    web.implicitly_wait(5)
    pdl  = web.current_window_handle
    for x in range(rlstart, rlend):

        web.implicitly_wait(1)
        inp = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtEnrollSeatNo"]')
        inp.send_keys(x)
        submit = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]')
        submit.click()

        web.implicitly_wait(2)
        web.implicitly_wait(2)

        # pdl  = web.current_window_handle
        handles =  web.window_handles
        for handle in handles:
            if(handle != pdl):
                switch_to_alert().accept()
                web.switch_to.window(handle)

                getresult = web.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(3) > strong').text
                if(getresult > 96.00):
                    resultCount += 1
                web.close()
                web.switch_to.window(pdl)

    web.implicitly_wait(2)
    
except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    alert_obj = web.switch_to.alert
    alert_obj.accept()
    
    

finally:
    print("end")
    web.quit()
    print(resultCount)
```

This is errors

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go through below code once.

I have not edited your code but it does what you ask for.

`while rlstart != rlend+1:` , `rlend+1` because if there is an increment, `156860` becomes `156861` and when `rlstart` is `156861`, it comes out the while loop and does not give `156861's` result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://msbte.org.in/DISRESLIVE2021CRSLDSEP/frmALYSUM21PBDisplay.aspx")
rlstart = 156857
rlend = 156860 # Have tested only for a few Seat no.
#rlend = 157299
while rlstart != rlend+1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtEnrollSeatNo").send_keys(rlstart) # To send the Seat no
        driver.find_element_by_id("btnSubmit").click() # To click on the submit button and exemption happens after this.
        # Collect all  the windows opened-up.
        handles = driver.window_handles
        # Switch to other window and extract the Seat no and percenatge.
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        seatno = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]").text
        per = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/strong").text
        print("Result of Seat no: {}".format(seatno))
        print("Percentage: {}".format(per))
        # Since percentage is in decimal but as a string, converting it into float is more accurate. Compare and increment.
        if float(per)>96.0:
            rlend+=1
            print("new rlend: {}".format(rlend))
        # Close the new window, switch back to parent window and clear before entering a new Seat no.
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtEnrollSeatNo").clear()
    except:
        print("Invalid Seat No : {}".format(rlstart))
        # Handle the alert, clear the field for next Seat no and continue. No need to switch between windows since no new window has opened up.
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
        driver.find_element_by_id("txtEnrollSeatNo").clear()
        pass
    rlstart+=1
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Result of Seat no: 156857
Percentage: 95.71
Result of Seat no: 156858
Percentage: 96.63
new rlend: 156861
Result of Seat no: 156859
Percentage: 86.11
Result of Seat no: 156860
Percentage: 90.29
Result of Seat no: 156861
Percentage: 96.17
new rlend: 156862
Result of Seat no: 156862
Percentage: 75.00
```

Comment: Although your code works great, it would be even more appreciable if you can add some explanation of what changes you did. That would make it more easy to understand the solution.

Comment: @demouser123 - Yes, Thank you for your suggestion. Have updated the code with required comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code.

1. `web.implicitly_wait(1)` does not insert actual pause in your code. It just sets timeout. How much time to wait for element to appear on the page. So when you define it twice

```
web.implicitly_wait(2)
web.implicitly_wait(2)
```

This doesn't give you a pause of 4 seconds, just defines the timeout for 2 seconds twice but not pausing your program flow.
Also you don't need to define this multiple times, just define it once and forgot about it.
Also we usually define the timeout to be 10-20-30 seconds, not 1-2 seconds. This can  cause test failures in case of slow internet connection / slow web site responces etc.

2. In case of correct seat number no alert appearing but the data is opened in a new window.
   So when the seat is correct `switch_to_alert().accept()` will fail - this is what actually happens since no alert appeared.
   I was working on making a correct code, but other people gave you working code. So you can read the explanations here and the working code there :)

Comment: yes. thank you. 2nd mistake I corrected. about the implicitly_wait. As we have 2 windows if we add one statement of wait at the beginning of the program having 10 / 30 seconds will it be applied for the new window also or for the current window?

Comment: AFAIK it is set on webdriver `driver` object. So it will work for all the windows managed by that driver.

Comment: @DhananjayGavali :  till the browser instance is alive it will be there, now when you do a `driver.close`, it does kill the newly opened browser windows.

Comment: In case you are closing the second window with `driver.close` while the first window remains existing the `driver` settings will remain. We are not closing the entire browser here with `driver.quit`

Answer (score 2):

Things to noted down :

1. You should not use implicit waits more than once.
2. Use explicit waits, or in dead cases use `time.sleep()`, the below code I have put sleep just for visual purpose.
3. You are comparing string with a float which is wrong.
4. There's a way to switch windows, and alert please see below.
5. Also, having said that, I would not recommend to mix `implicit` with `explicit`.
6. I have reduced the value of `rlend`, for testing purpose, you will have to increase that and see if that works.

**Code :-**

```
web  = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
web.maximize_window()
#web.implicitly_wait(50)
web.get("https://msbte.org.in/DISRESLIVE2021CRSLDSEP/frmALYSUM21PBDisplay.aspx")
wait = WebDriverWait(web, 20)

resultCount = 0

rlstart = 156857
rlend = 156861

#157299
try:
    for x in range(rlstart, rlend):
        orginal_window = web.current_window_handle
        seat_input_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='txtEnrollSeatNo']")))
        time.sleep(1)
        seat_input_box.clear()
        seat_input_box.send_keys(rlstart)
        rlstart = rlstart + 1
        submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='btnSubmit']")))
        submit.click()
        try:
            print("Alert was not present, but new windows was")
            handles = web.window_handles
            web.switch_to.window(handles[1])
            time.sleep(1)
            web.maximize_window()
            time.sleep(2)
            web.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)")
            time.sleep(2)
            getresult = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'Aggregate Marks : ')]/following-sibling::td[2]/strong"))).text
            getresult_dec = float(getresult)
            if getresult_dec > 96.00 :
                resultCount = resultCount + 1
                print("Kill the browser in else block.")
                web.close()
            else:
                web.close()
                print("Kill the browser in else block.")
        except:
            print("Means alert is present. ")
            a = web._switch_to.alert
            a.accept()
            web.switch_to.default_content()
        time.sleep(3)
        web.switch_to.window(orginal_window)

except:
    pass

print(resultCount)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: You've made a lot of changes to the original code login, apart from the float comparison. So I think you should also add a summary of those changes as well. Also I ran your code on two separate machines and it only opens correctly for first one and then the new browser window doesn't open.

Comment: @demouser123 : I understand that, but since this is a very specific question and does not really have a general audience, I did not put it, but here you go, this works great now, please run and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: @Dhananjay Gavali : You can now run the code, it seems to working flawlessly. Also I have actually reduce `rlend` to test in my local, you can increase the value and let me know if you face any issue while running the code.

Comment: @cruisepandey : it's not identifying the Webdriverwait can you please also add the import statements how they should be included. I'm new with python

Comment: @DhananjayGavali :  Please see above I have updated it.